# How to count in SQL for specific columns

Tags: sql

How can calculate which ID has paid the most in average?

I tried this, but i get only on query instead of two:

```
select stelltan 
from hilfsarbeiter 
group by stelltan, arbeiternr 
HAVING avg(lohn) >= all (SELECT avg(lohn) 
                         from hilfsarbeiter 
                         group by stelltan, arbeiternr)
```

[image]

Comment: Please provide a relevant and minimal sample data showcasing your requirements, and expected output. Refer this link on how to frame a good SQL question: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952/2469308)

Comment: (1) I removed the incompatible database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.  (2) There is no "id" in your data, so your question does not make much sense.  You can edit the question to clarify.

Comment: I don't see _imkernr_ there, show a sample data and expected results please as _formatted text_

Comment: Just do aggregation query for maximum with aggregation sub-query for average.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You possibly are looking to calculate average of `lohn` for a group of "id" (`stelltan`). Once we have calculated the average for every "id"; we just need to sort the result-set in Descending order by "average paid" value, and consider the "id" with highest average value using `Limit 1`

```
SELECT stelltan, AVG(lohn) AS average_paid  
FROM hilfsarbeiter 
GROUP BY stelltan 
ORDER BY average_paid DESC LIMIT 1
```

---

Since you [cannot use Limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53107495/how-to-count-in-sql-for-specific-columns/53107611?noredirect=1#comment93111037_53107611), we can modify your existing attempt (subquery based approach):

```
SELECT stelltan 
FROM hilfsarbeiter 
GROUP BY stelltan 
HAVING AVG(lohn) >= ALL (SELECT AVG(lohn) 
                         FROM hilfsarbeiter 
                         GROUP BY stelltan)
```

Comment: Something like that, for example id paid 1000,840,1200,1020 so average is 1015 and for id 2 is 376 and so on. I need to get who has the biggest average .

Comment: @VedranD check my answer. It does the same thing.

Comment: I know thank you for help, but I am not allowed to use any constants, so LIMIT doesnt work for me.... Is there maybe solution with MAX()?

Comment: @VedranD is it some kind of homework challenge ? There are other ways possible too, like using a subquery.

Comment: @VedranD check the updated answer; use the second query.